# How to apply skipping logic in Confirmit tool for skipping questions?

Tags: survey, productivity-power-tools

### How to apply skipping logic in Confirmit tool for skipping questions?

---

Answer (score 0):

If you want to skip those questions in all the cases then put them inside false condition.

1. Add If condition (node/element)
2. Move all questions inside "Then"
3. Write "false" in if (expression)